# Range.Formula application-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

```
objSheet.Range("L20").Formula = _
   "=INDEX(Sheet2!B2:B4824;MATCH(Sheet!F16;Sheet2!A2:A4824; 0))"
```

Why does this line fail? I've tried both static and dynamic cell references. I've tried `Range.Formula`, `Cells.Value`, etc... to no avail. I even made a separate function that constructs the string so I can invoke the variable instead of the direct string, but no dice. Also tried stating the range several different ways.

The sheets are named correctly (the formula works without hiccup when manually inserted) and `objSheet` is defined (the rest of the macro works fine). Removing `objSheet` does nothing.

What on earth am I missing?

Comment: What is the error message that it's giving you?

Comment: Shouldn't commas separate the arguments in the index and match formulas and not semi-colons?

Comment: The edit window wouldn't accept my formatting attempts... but I see someone took care of it. But the error was Application or Object-defined error. The comment and answer below concerning commas instead of semi-colons were correct and working.

Comment: @vsaraas are your sheet names the standard sheet1, sheet2...etc?

Comment: Glad to hear that worked, Give Sam a checkmark click for his effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using semi colons. You need to use commas.

```
objSheet.Range("L20").Formula = "=INDEX(Sheet2!B2:B4824;MATCH(Sheet!F16;Sheet2!A2:A4824; 0))"
```

Should be

```
objSheet.Range("L20").Formula = "=INDEX(Sheet2!B2:B4824,MATCH(Sheet!F16,Sheet2!A2:A4824, 0))"
```

Comment: Something I just learned a week or so ago - there is a setting somewhere in Excel that makes the semicolon a valid parameter separator. This isn't necessarily the issue.

Comment: It is defined by your "List Separator" within windows.  Go to "Region and Language" ->"Formats Tab" -> "Additional settings..." -> "List Separator:"

Comment: This was the case for me. Funny that Excel converts the commas to semi-colons in the actual spreadsheet... but I have a follow-up question: why does Excel put a #NAME error on the formula, only to remove the error and display the correct result if I select the formula line of the given cell and then deselect?

Comment: @vsoraas a #NAME error is Excel's way of saying it does not understand part (or all) of a `cell reference` within your formula.  This usually appears when you misspell a sheet name, or misspell a named range.

Comment: Everything is spelled correctly, but I discovered the cause...

I use a language-localized Version of Excel. Which means that I have to use localized formula names. But in the VB script, I apparently have to use the English names. Using the localized names produces the #NAME error initially, but as soon as Excel "examines" the formula I guess, it remembers that it's supposed to know how to interpret this name as well...